# Remove QComboBox listView shadow effect

Tags: qt, qt4, qcombobox

By default, the `QComboBox` listview has shadow effect. Is there a way to remove it? Is the shadow controlled from `QStyle` or in some other way?

[image: qcombobox shadow]

Answer (score 4):

The shadow effect is not a Qt specific thing, its a Desktop theme specific thing. The shadow depends on the style/theme your desktop environment is using. If your style/theme defines shadows for QComboBox then Qt will very promptly draw it. That said, you may search for a style that does not draw a shadow. I got the effect by doing so:

```
cb = QComboBox()
cb.addItems( [ '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6' ] )
cb.setStyle( QStyleFactory.create( "Polyester" ) )
cb.setStyleSheet( "QComboBox QAbstractItemView { border: 1 px solid gray; }" )
cb.show()
```

For this, you must have a compatible theme like polyester listed by `QStyleFactory.keys()`. I tried with the snazzy Breeze style and the famous QtCurve style, but they draws a shadow always. You may achieve the same using `GTK+` and the `Cleanlooks` styles.

FYI: Polyester is one of the styles that comes with KDE.

Here is a screenshot of the above code:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Marcus, let me try

Answer (score 1):

Okay, that might be working for someone who has themes without shadow effects but I have them, so I finally found a simple way to make it work.

```
self.comboBox.findChild(QFrame).setWindowFlags(Qt.Popup | Qt.NoDropShadowWindowHint)
```

combobox has one QFrame inside. Its window effect makes the shadow.
We can erase that effect with the aforementioned line.
Careful, don't put both, otherwise you won't open the popup.

I know it's been a while since this post was made but I haven't found any other solutions.