# Styling of QComboBox: How to remove shadow on listview?

Tags: qt, qt4, qcombobox, qtstylesheets

I am trying to make Qt application restyling using qss (qt stylesheet) and QProxyStyle. And can't find a way to remove shadow of listview.
Seems that it is not possible to do with the style, but i beleive it should be possible with the QProxyStyle.

[image: qcombobox shadow]

Comment: This question was asked before, but don't know if the answer was helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27739536/remove-qcombobox-listview-shadow-effect

Comment: @xsquared, thanks. I saw that question, but answer is not acceptable for me. And I have feeling that answer not helpful for almost all who face this problem and make styling of qt application.

Comment: Asking the question again is not the way to get better answers. You're literally asking the same question. Simply upvote the other one, and perhaps edit it to make it better. I'll close this one as a duplicate.